# How to merge data from same month in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have this code which displays the data monthwise. Now i need to total the data which fall in same month. For example if there are 2 data(2,4) from Month may, the final output should be May - 6 . Currently it's in table as 
May- 2 
May- 4

```
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { Year: selectedYear, Filtertxt: selectedQuarter},
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {

                var tr;
                var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    var date = new Date(data[i].CompDt);

                    var month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];

                    var monthdata = data[i].ID;
                    var totalamt = data[i].TotalAmt;
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + month + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + monthdata+ "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + totalamt + "</td>");
                    $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
                }
                tr = $('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white" />');
                tr.append("<td></td>");
                tr.append("<td></td>");
                tr.append("<td></td>");

                $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
            }
            else {

                tr = $('<tr/>');
                tr.append("<th colspan='10' style='text-align:center'>No Data to display</th>");

                $('#GraphTable').append(tr);
            }

        } //end of success
    });
```

Comment: how does you data looks like i mean post your json data you are getting in response.

Comment: If the final output is the sum of all amounts of a month, what would the `monthdata` be?

Answer (score 0):

You can format the JSON data first

```
const formatted = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  const date = new Date(item.CompDt);
  const month = months[date.getMonth()];

  if (!formatted[month]) {
    formatted[month] = item.TotalAmt;
  } else {
    formatted[month] += item.TotalAmt;
  }
});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    ID: 1,
    CompDt: '01/01/2017',
    TotalAmt: 2,
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    CompDt: '01/01/2017',
    TotalAmt: 4,
  },
  {
    ID: 3,
    CompDt: '02/01/2017',
    TotalAmt: 3,
  },
  {
    ID: 4,
    CompDt: '04/01/2017',
    TotalAmt: 10,
  },
];
const months = [
  'Jan',
  'Feb',
  'Mar',
  'Apr',
  'May',
  'Jun',
  'Jul',
  'Aug',
  'Sep',
  'Oct',
  'Nov',
  'Dec',
];
const formatted = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  const date = new Date(item.CompDt);
  const month = months[date.getMonth()];

  if (!formatted[month]) {
    formatted[month] = item.TotalAmt;
  } else {
    formatted[month] += item.TotalAmt;
  }
});

console.log(formatted);
```

You can then use the formatted data but not sure how you're supposed to handle the `monthdata (data[i].ID)`.